# Magento 2 translate field from wysiwyg

Tags: magento2.2.2, wysiwyg, inline-translations, translate

How can one using csv file to translate from wysiwyg field: e.g

I have in the backend of Magento a field :

```
<h3 class="eyeCatching">Opening Hours</h3>
 <p>Monday - 10am to 5pm 
Tuesday - 10am to 5pm 
Wednesday - 10am to 5pm 
Thursday - 10am to 7pm
Friday - 10am to 5pm
Saturday - 10am to 5pm
Sunday - 11am to 5pm</p>
```

to e.g Ducth:
    `Openingstijden
    Maandag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur
    Dinsdag - van 10:00 tot 17:00 uur
    Woensdag - 10.00 tot 17.00 uur
    Donderdag - 10.00 tot 19.00 uur
    Vrijdag - van 10:00 tot 17:00 uur
    Zaterdag: van 10:00 tot 17:00 uur
    Zondag - 11:00 tot 17:00 uur`

I've tried in the csv file:

> "Opening Hours Monday - 10am to 5pm Tuesday - 10am to 5pm Wednesday - 10am to 5pm Thursday - 10am to 7pm Friday - 10am to 5pm Saturday - 10am to 5pm Sunday - 11am to 5pm","Openingstijden maandag Maandag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur Dinsdag - van 10:00 tot 17:00 uur Woensdag - 10.00 tot 17.00 uur Donderdag - 10.00 tot 19.00 uur Vrijdag - van 10:00 tot 17:00 uur Zaterdag: van 10:00 tot 17:00 uur Zondag - 11:00 tot 17:00 uur",module,module,My_Module

I am calling at the front end like so:

```
<?php echo __("%1", $block->getOpeningHours());?>
```

I've also tried in the csv file like so:

> "%1","%1",module,My_Module

But that isn't translating!thanks

Comment: Are you using static block?

Comment: @SukumarGorai  I am using a custom module where I have a wysiwyg : to enter this information. but would like to translate using the csv file

Comment: How you calling it on frontend?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Updated answer

Comment: Check my answer. Also paste the same code which is in first column to your html(editor).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line in your csv file:

```
<h3 class="eyeCatching">Opening Hours</h3><p>Monday - 10am to 5pm</br>Tuesday - 10am to 5pm</br>Wednesday - 10am to 5pm</br>Thursday - 10am to 7pm</br>Friday - 10am to 5pm</br>Saturday - 10am to 5pm</br>
Sunday - 11am to 5pm</p>,<h3 class="eyeCatching">Openingstijden</h3><p>Maandag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur</br>Dinsdag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur</br>Woensdag - 10.00 tot 17.00 uur</br>Donderdag - 10.00 tot 19.00 uur</br>Vrijdag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur</br>Zaterdag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur</br>Zondag - 11:00 tot 17:00 uur</p>
```

Comment: I've tried to hardcode in my phtml file like so :

`echo __('<h3 class="eyeCatching">Opening Hours</h3><p>Monday - 10am to 5pm</br>Tuesday - 10am to 5pm</br>Wednesday - 10am to 5pm</br>Thursday - 10am to 7pm</br>Friday - 10am to 5pm</br>Saturday - 10am to 5pm</br>
Sunday - 11am to 5pm</p>')` 

And csv with your answer but not success, what only work is if I remove the html tags from from phtml file and the left of csv and remove html tags but that isnt' good as my content is dinamic not harded coded

Answer (score 0):

Need Slight Changes From @Sukumar Gorai answer it was a problem with the `class="eyeCatching"` and dynamic field having an enter key.

So the final code would be :

```
<h3 class=""eyeCatching"">Opening Hours</h3><p>Monday - 10am to 
5pm</br>Tuesday - 10am to 5pm</br>Wednesday - 10am to 5pm</br>Thursday 
- 10am to 7pm</br>Friday - 10am to 5pm</br>Saturday - 10am to 5pm</br>
Sunday - 11am to 5pm</p>,<h3 class="eyeCatching">Openingstijden</h3>
<p>Maandag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur</br>Dinsdag - 10:00 tot 17:00 
uur</br>Woensdag - 10.00 tot 17.00 uur</br>Donderdag - 10.00 tot 19.00 
uur</br>Vrijdag - 10:00 tot 17:00 uur</br>Zaterdag - 10:00 tot 17:00 
uur</br>Zondag - 11:00 tot 17:00 uur</p>
```

**NOTE:** Double double double quotes added to class like so:

```
<h3 class=""eyeCatching"">
```

Apart from that when the dynamic field is entered it should be all in one line then everything works ok.